# one Dataset from multiple csv files

Tags: data, dataset, core-language

In one folder I have many csv files, all sharing an identical header.  I can use `SemanticImport` to produce a `Dataset` from each and then `Join` these into a single `Dataset`.  Is that the right way to proceed?  Or does WL somehow support a bulk read (like say R's `readbulk` package)?